# URL mapping on Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I am facing one issue in populating URL routes for my endpoints in my app for logging purpose.

The issue arise when using application under Apache wsgi alias, like

> localhost/mywebapp/

My development apache webapp.cong file,

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess webapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/home/user/projects/webapp/
    WSGIScriptAlias /mywebapp /home/user/projects/webapp/app.wsgi

    <directory /home/user/projects/webapp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

When I try to fetch list of URL's using below code,

```
for rule in current_app.url_map.iter_rules('static'):
    print("Endpoint: ", rule.endpoint, "URL: ", rule.rule)
```

**Output** (one of the endpoint & url):

```
Endpoint: 'static' URL: '/static/<path:filename>'
```

I was expecting URL with WSGI alias but I'm not getting url prepended with WSGI alias.

**Expected output:**

```
Endpoint: 'static' URL: '/mywebapp/static/<path:filename>'
```

Another interesting thing is when I try to fetch URL with url_for() function, I'm getting proper URL

```
print(url_for('static', filename='js/require.js'))
```

Output

```
/mywebapp/static/js/require.js
```

How do I get WSGI prepend URL using **current_app.url_map.iter_rules()** function.

Comment: Have you considered serving the static files with your webserver?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do? The problem may be more with what you are trying to do than the observed behaviour. The behaviour you see is correct. WSGI applications shouldn't be coded with fixed knowledge of the mount point. The mount point is only available in a request, passed in via ``SCRIPT_NAME`` in the WSGI request environ dictionary and in Flask accessible as ``script_root`` on the request object. Methods such as ``url_for()`` are designed to work out full URL including the mount point.